# Update Windows Server 2022 With Exchange 2019 using a proxy server to avoid giving the machine an internet connection

Tags: proxy, virtual-machines, update, windows-server-2022, exchange-2019

We have cloned our production e-mail server to a Hyper-V vm. We need to fix some update issues we have with our production server and as such we have restored the server from a backup so we cant test things.

The problem is that the issues we are facing are update related. And we don't want to give the test VM inter net so we don't mess up our Domain and production e-mail service.

This VM is on a Virtual Switch of Hyper-V and is using VLAN.This is so we can keep the subnet of our production environment and connect other production machines such as a DC or domain clients to the test environment . Thus simulating our production network as well.

Is there a way to give the test server internet via a proxy vm? maybe a windows core server that is on the bridge switch of the Hyper-V host. Would this cause trouble for our production domain?

Comment: It is possible, but why not copy the updates without the Internet and install them?

Comment: Because if it can be automated it should be in my opinion. We have a lot of systems and servers to maintain and we do not have the time to find specific updates per server and install the manually. Never the less this will be our final choice if we can not achieve what we asked here.

Comment: You are confusing Internet with automation. Nearly all organizations automate the update of servers without requiring Internet access, proxy or no proxy. There are more products, tools, and solutions for this one thing than anything else. They all copy/distribute the updates internally though.